# Sequence numbers for individual values in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In Sql Server 2008

my select query result is like below.

```
Col1             Col2          Col3
------------------------------------------
1001             HO            160.00
1001             HO             40.00
1001             HO            200.00
1002             HO             10.00
1002             HO            130.00
1003             HO             10.00
1003             HO            130.00
1003             HO            130.00
1003             HO            230.00
```

Now, I want the select result as below (please find change in Col2)

```
Col1             Col2          Col3
------------------------------------------
1001             HO1            160.00
1001             HO2             40.00
1001             HO3            200.00
1002             HO1             10.00
1002             HO2            130.00
1003             HO1             10.00
1003             HO2            130.00
1003             HO3            130.00
1003             HO4            230.00
```

Experts over-there... please help me in extracting the data like above.

Comment: please provide your query

Comment: Have a look into ROW_NUMBER(), using PARTITION BY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am just created sample data and gave you the query.So you can implement in your original query

```
declare @t table(id int,Name varchar(10))

    insert into @t (id,name)values (1,'HO')
    insert into @t (id,name)values (1,'HO')
    insert into @t (id,name)values (2,'HO')
    insert into @t (id,name)values (2,'HO')

    select id,name +CAST(row_number()OVER(PARTITION BY id order by name )AS VARCHAR)rn from @t
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select col1,
col2+cast(row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col1) as varchar(10)) as col2, 
col3 from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  Col1,
        Col2 + CAST([Row] AS VARCHAR(10)) Col2,
        Col3
FROM    (
SELECT  *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Col1) [Row]
FROM    [Table]) LU
```

This may also help you.